# Is it possible to make stdout and stderr output be of different colors in XTerm or Konsole?

Tags: linux, console, colors, terminal, stream

**Is it even achievable?**

I would like the output from a command’s stderr to be rendered in a different color than stdout (for example, in red).

I need such a modification to work with the Bash shell in the Konsole, XTerm, or GNOME Terminal terminal emulators on Linux.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a matter for a program writer? Surely you can muster up something (as in proposed answers, but it will probably make complete mess out of programs that already color their output.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's a solution that combines some of the good ideas already presented.

Create a function in a bash script:

```
color() ( set -o pipefail; "$@" 2>&1>&3 | sed $'s,.*,\e[31m&\e[m,' >&2 ) 3>&1
```

Use it like this:

```
$ color command -program -args
```

It will show the command's `stderr` in red.

Keep reading for an explanation of how it works.  There are some interesting features demonstrated by this command.

- `color()...` — Creates a bash function called color.
- `set -o pipefail` — This is a shell option that preserves the error return code of a command whose output is piped into another command.  This is done in a subshell, which is created by the parentheses, so as not to change the pipefail option in the outer shell.
- `"$@"` — Executes the arguments to the function as a new command.  `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`
- `2>&1` — Redirects the `stderr` of the command to `stdout` so that it becomes `sed`'s `stdin`.
- `>&3` — Shorthand for `1>&3`, this redirects `stdout` to a new temporary file descriptor `3`.  `3` gets routed back into `stdout` later.
- `sed ...` — Because of the redirects above, `sed`'s `stdin` is the `stderr` of the executed command.  Its function is to surround each line with color codes.
- `$'...'` A bash construct that causes it to understand backslash-escaped characters
- `.*` — Matches the entire line.
- `\e[31m` — The ANSI escape sequence that causes the following characters to be red
- `&` — The `sed` replace character that expands to the entire matched string (the entire line in this case).
- `\e[m` — The ANSI escape sequence that resets the color.
- `>&2` — Shorthand for `1>&2`, this redirects `sed`'s `stdout` to `stderr`.
- `3>&1` — Redirects the temporary file descriptor `3` back into `stdout`.

Here's an extension of the same concept that also makes STDOUT green:

```
function stdred() (
    set -o pipefail;
    (
        "$@" 2>&1>&3 |
        sed $'s,.*,\e[31m&\e[m,' >&2
    ) 3>&1 |
    sed $'s,.*,\e[32m&\e[m,'
)
```

Comment: actually you should put "$@" instead of $* or you'll run into problems with spaces.

Comment: Nice solution. Drawback I instantly found: color ll <somefile> will not work, although ll alias is defined.

Comment: Another drawback with the `color` function is that the exit code will be lost unless you set before `set -o pipefail` (see http://bclary.com/blog/2006/07/20/pipefail-testing-pipeline-exit-codes/)

Comment: @didi_X8 You can make aliases work by using the eval keyword: color eval ll, for example.  Eval has the unfortunate side effect of losing any quotes you placed around arguments, which is why I am not including it in the general solution.

Comment: Too bad lines of stdout and stderr won't come back in their original order -- with a program outputting one line to stdout, then stderr, then stdout, then stderr I'm getting both stdout lines and then both stderr lines.

Answer (score 17):

You can also check out stderred: https://github.com/sickill/stderred

Comment: Seemed to work well when I tested it with a build script in a separate terminal, but I'm hesitant to use it globally (in `.bashrc`). Thanks though!

Comment: Note for OSX users: http://superuser.com/questions/244964/mac-os-x-bashrc-not-working also where would be the logical place to put the .dylib? ~/stderred.dylib ?

Comment: Bold-Red example in doc is broken -- try this instead: https://gist.github.com/p-i-/8628609

Comment: Oooh, this modifies libc to do the coloring in-process, which avoids all the ordering/race problems of two-separate-pipes approaches!

Answer (score 7):

I can't see that there is any way for the terminal emulator to do this.

The interface between the terminal emulator and the shell/app is via a pseudo-tty, where the terminal emulator is on the master side and the shell/app on the other. The shell/app have both stdout and stderr connected to the same pty, so when the terminal emulator reads from the pty for the shell/app output it can no longer tell which was written to stdout and which to stderr.

You will have to use one of the solutions that intercepts the data between the application and the slave-pty and inserts escape codes to control the terminal output colo(u)r.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution to color stdout in red is to pipe it through `grep`:

```
program | grep .
```

This should not require installing anything, as `grep` should be already installed everywhere.

Taken from [Dennis’s comment on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/453598/determine-if-output-is-stdout-or-stderr#comment529379_453604).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little Awk script that will print everything you pass it in red.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ printf("%c[%dm%s%c[0m\n", 0x1B, 31, $0, 0x1B); fflush() }
```

It simply prints each line it receives on **stdin** within the necessary escape codes to display it in red. It is followed by an escape code to reset the terminal.

(If you need a different color, change the second argument in the above `printf` call from 31 to the number corresponding to the desired color.)

Save it to `colr.awk`, do a `chmod a+x`, and use it like so:

```
$ my_program | ./colr.awk
```

It has the drawback that lines may not be displayed in order, because stderr goes directly to the console, while stdout is piped through an additional process.

Comment: There's no guarantee that stdout and stderr will appear in order anyway.  They're separate pipes with separate buffering, and stdout is usually buffered in the process memory as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the standard escape sequences on stderr. Have a look at [this](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Hilite](http://directory.fsf.org/project/hilite/) will do this.  It's a lightweight solution, but you have to invoke it for each command, eg. `hilite gcc myprog.c`.  A more radical approach is built in to my experimental shell [Gush](http://wiki.tcl.tk/23446) which shows stderr from all commands run in red, stdout in black.  Either way is very useful for software builds where you have lots of output with a few error messages that could easily be missed if not highlighted.