# Bash, how to visually distinguish stdout from stderr?

Tags: bash

I need to visually distinguish, at a glance, stdout output from stderr output coming from a Bash script I am debugging.

Can I pipe the command through some "visualisation enhancer" UNIX filter that would at least colour stderr "red", if not even prepend some tag to each stderr line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a few options.
Easiest would be to use [hilite](http://directory.fsf.org/project/hilite/).

Other options would include writing custom shell wrapper to colorize the input.

A few options are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763891/can-stdout-and-stderr-use-different-colors-under-xterm-konsole) (note, that they are pretty much xterm-specific).

Comment: This is exactly what I need but how inconvenient that it comes as a C source code file and not a package on any distro or on MacPorts? `gcc -Wall -o hilite hilite.c` works but...

Comment: It's in `brew`. `brew install hilite`. Ditch MacPorts, embrace http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/ :)

Comment: Or well, don't ditch MacPorts. They coexist rather nicely, unless you install same software from both sources.

Comment: It's probably time for me to embrace `brew`, huh?

Comment: Shrug, not advocating any nor oppose any. Have both, use both :)

Comment: Downvoted as a low-quality answer. It's not much more than two links and a very vague DIY suggestion.
No usage instructions, neither in the answer nor in the linked page. I can't figure out how to use it. It's got no man page and no `--help`. `echo "hello" | hilite` throws an error (and so does anything else piped to it).

Comment: Hi @favoretti, I found no decent solution within a certain timeframe and wasn't able to build on this answer. The answer may have aged better if it had followed the guidance of "[provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)".